# Substitute in Google Sheet but Ignore Particular string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using this formula in Google Sheets to substitute some string of words.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Z2:Z36000,"@ ", "OF ")," ALUMINUM BAG  ", ""),"BOX IN",""),"BOX OF",""),"",""))
```

The data

```
DATA Column        Expected Results
BOX OF BEER        BEER
BOX IN BASEMENT    BASEMENT
BOX OF GIFT        BOX OF GIFT
```

I would like to exclude "BOX OF GIFT" with Substitute. Can i do that? OR any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use in `B2`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"^(?:(BOX OF GIFT$)|BOX (?:OF|IN) )(.*)","$1$2")
```

Or:

```
=IF(A2="BOX OF GIFT",A2;REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\bBOX (?:OF|IN)\b *",""))
```

I'll see if I can come up with a cleaner option...

Comment: Wicked! Thanks @JrdV